# Uploading a new APK after unpublishing older app

Tags: android, google-play, apk

There is an app created and was published on Google Play store. Then it was not getting updated because of missing keystore. So the exiting app was unpublished and a new apk was created with new package name and version number.

Then, even if the new signed apk was created with newer version code and package name, still an error is appearing "you should either add a new apk or deactivate an existing apk to create a new release".

Can someone help out  ? Is anything missed in the process ?

Answer (score 5):

You can only update the existing Apk of an unpublished app with the new version code, in google play console you cannot add an Apk with a different package name.

You can add Apk having the same package name and keystore as previously. you can also see this document for further details.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7159011?hl=en

Comment: I have unpublished the app since I don't have keystore for that. And then I have created a new APK as mentioned in my question and was trying to create a new release entirely.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of knowledge I think google play store doesn't support changing the apk for the same project .You should create another app project in play console for the new apk and add it to release.

Comment: I am creating another project only. After unpublishing first project, I am creating a new project. APK for this have a  new Package Id. I am facing this error message in new project only  " you should either add a new apk or deactivate an existing apk to create a new release ".

Answer (score 1):

I'am sure that you have uploaded the app and filled the content rating. Then you should have to go to edit release and create your release. Re uploading was your problem.Or post the error image to help you more

Comment: We have a message there "You must upload an APK before taking the content rating questionnaire.". So first we should upload APK. But I am not able to upload apk and the error message is 'Unable to upload APK' . On clicking Review, I am seeing the message as 'you should either add a new apk or deactivate an existing apk to create a new release'.

Comment: Deactivate the apk from release management and upload the new one with new version.

Comment: Can't see any option to disable the existing APK.

Answer (score 0):

As many others have answered I will repeat, but try to repeat more clearly.

Every app has a *package name* sometimes called an *application id*. It's the string like `com.google.android.gm`. As far as Google Play is concerned, it doesn't care what you do in your project in Android Studio, or Unity or any other development platform. If the app has the same package name, it is the same app. If it has a different package name, it is a different app.

You say you are trying to create a new release with a different package name. This can't be done. As far as Google is concerned, you are creating a brand new app.

Have you uploaded your APK with your new package name? If you have, can you provide a screenshot? Then people might be able to more clearly see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the response. For now I can't provide the screenshot here because I don't have apk with me now. However, as what you said "You say you are trying to create a new release with a different package name. This can't be done. As far as Google is concerned, you are creating a brand new app."   - Yes, I am trying to create a brand new app that way. For me the old app can be neglected now. But even if I try to do create a brand new app, its howing APK upload error.

Comment: I think saying 'New release' was confusing. Its actually a new App with different package name. And to be more clear, I have unpublished the old app. I am not sure if by unpublishing the app, APK is also de-activated or not. Since I am facing the error "you should either add a new apk or deactivate an existing apk to create a new release"

Comment: I can only repeat myself. Google doesn't know about the connection between your old app and your new app, if they have different package names. As far as Google is concerned they are completely separate apps. The unpublish status of your old App is irrelevant if the package names are indeed different.

Comment: Yes, that's what I know. I am not sure why this is getting issues. I have to contact Play Store Support for that.  Though, one thing I can look for here - Package name is updated at 2 places in the app. So, application Id should also be changes ? Since we have two different things - Application Id and Package Name.

Comment: application id and package name are two different names for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also changed the name of the package via Refractor in Android Studio. I wanted to upload the same app with a new package. And it was still giving me the error that the package already exists, so I had to change the applicationId in build.grade App:module.

[image]

After this, it does not replace the old app on phone. Instead, it creates a new one, also Playstore uploaded the app.